# How do I get the Amazon Cognito hosted UI to prompt for TOTP?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am assuming that I would be prompted based off of the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-mfa-totp.html), which specifically states:

> If your app is using the Amazon Cognito hosted UI to sign in users, the UI shows a second page for your user to enter the TOTP password after they submit their user name and password.

Under the "MFA and Verifications" section of the user pool, I have checked the following:

- Do you want to enable Multi-Factor Authentication (MFA)?

  - Optional
- Which second factors do you want to enable?

  - Time-based One-time Password

I have added a single test user that is verified.

From there, I followed the documentation to both [Associate the TOTP Token](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AssociateSoftwareToken.html) and [Verify the TOTP Token](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_VerifySoftwareToken.html), confirming I got the secret code in the response for calling AssociateSoftwareToken and a 'SUCCESS' in the response for VerifySoftwareToken.

At this point, I believe when I use the hosted UI sign-in page, I should be prompted to enter a one-time-password after submitting my username/password, and upon successful verification of that, be redirected to the signin callback URL specfied in my app client.

However, I am being redirected immediately after submitting the username and password and there is no prompt for entering a TOTP.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by explicitly calling [SetUserMFAPreference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_SetUserMFAPreference.html) after setting up TOTP for the test account. My assumption that associating and verifying TOTP automatically changed Cognito's behavior with respect to the authentication flow of the user was mistaken. It also required me to tell Cognito to enable and use the TOTP for the user.

The crux of my original confusion was that generating and associating a software token to generate OTPs for a user did not *enable* it for the user. A call to `SetUserMFAPreference` to enable it for the user was also required. Once that was done, it worked as expected. For instance, to enable software MFA and set it as preferred:

```
{
   "AccessToken": "xyz123",
   "SoftwareTokenMfaSettings": { 
      "Enabled": true,
      "PreferredMfa": true
   }
}
```

There is also an [admin version of the API call](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminSetUserMFAPreference.html) that can achieve the same result.

Comment: Makes sense, since you set MFA as being optional

Comment: Could you please be more clear? What exactly did you call?

Comment: See https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cognito-user-pool-totp-mfa/ for some helpful examples

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else who stumbles upon this and *still* isn't getting prompted for their TOTP, you may also need to clear your cookies. Even if your pool is not set up to remember user devices, without clearing the cookies you may still be able to log in without the TOTP.

Comment: how to clear the cookie for TOTP. I set expiry and deleted all the cookie from browser but It not work.

Comment: @SunilDevre - I simply deleted the cookies from browser and it worked for me. It sounds like your problem might lie elsewhere...

Answer (score 2):

After messing around with this problem, I reckon that AWS just gave up on this and moved towards using Amplify.

Use the Amplify libraries and their Amplify UI components.

The Auth component will prompt the user at first login with a QR code.

https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/getting-started/q/platform/js/#option-1-use-pre-built-ui-components

Comment: After a great deal of searching, this worked for me. TOTP and a bunch of error-handling works flawlessly out of the box with the Authenticator UI component. The thing that wasn't obvious is that you _can_ use Amplify UI components without using the Amplify CLI tool and the Amplify applications in the cloud. Learn how [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58439834/1749551).

Comment: Be aware that the Authenticator UI component does not use the OAuth2 framework. It uses the SRP protocol. The Amplify [federatedSignIn()](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/blob/be53c6187057728a9e2cf24265324fd1f470e5e0/packages/auth/src/Auth.ts#L1774_) uses OAuth2 for signing in.