# Using AWS Amplify for android for Auth without connecting to AWS (amplify cli)

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am trying to integrate AWS Cognito to an existing android project. All resources lead me to use Amplify. I need only Amplify Auth.

With a js web app I managed to setup amplify Auth manually without CLI using [Is it possible to use the amplify framework without using the cli?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56455901/is-it-possible-to-use-the-amplify-framework-without-using-the-cli)

While trying to set it up for Android all documentation asks to run `amplify init` which would require access to AWS through access key/ profile.

Even [Manual Setup Instructions](https://docs.amplify.aws/sdk/auth/getting-started/q/platform/android/#manual-setup), depend on files created with `amplify init`

Any direction on how to create the files manually or configure Amplify.auth without the files would be greatly appreciated.